# Mysql multiple select statements in single query with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table
*users*
with id,name,type,active,...

i have another table *orders*
with orderid,userid,...

i want to update orders table in such a way that

`UPDATE orders SET userid=(SELECT id FROM users WHERE type="some" and active=1)`

but my problem is
if `SELECT id FROM users WHERE type="some" and active=1` doesnt have any result 
i want to use 
`SELECT id FROM users WHERE type="some" limit 0,1`

ie the first result

i can do this easly in any language like php/python etc but i just have access to mysql server so cannot do that

but how can i do in pure sql in single query

i tried if statement but not working

Comment: `SELECT id FROM users WHERE type="some" order by active <> 1 limit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using `ORDER BY`:

```
UPDATE orders o
    SET userid = (SELECT u.id
                  FROM users u
                  WHERE u.type = 'some'
                  ORDER BY active DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```

This assumes that `active` only takes on the values `0` and `1`.  If there are other values, use `ORDER BY (active = 1) DESC`.

Performance should be fine with an index on `users(type, active, id)`.

Another method uses aggregation and `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE orders o
    SET userid = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN u.id END),
                                  MAX(u.id)
                                 )
                  FROM users u
                  WHERE u.type = 'some'
                 );
```

I would expect the `ORDER BY` to be a wee bit faster, but sometimes MySQL surprises me with aggregations in correlated subqueries.  That said, if you have very few rows for a given type, the performance difference may not be noticeable.